# Firm fixed effects changes sign on coefficient

Tags: interpretation, regression-coefficients

I am a rookie when i comes to statistics and need some guidance on how to interpret the fact that when I include firm fixed effects in my model the coefficients for one of my explanatory variable changes its sign. I find it hard to seek for information regarding the basics surrounding fixed effects, the information I find is too hard for me to understand. In general, what really happens when you include firm fixed effects? How can one explain that the coefficient changes sign from positive to negative?

Please help a rookie out.

Best regards

Comment: most likely the coefficient you introduced, is correlated to the one which the sign changes

Comment: What does that really mean? if i, before i included the firm fixed effects, found a positive significant relation between my independent and dependent variable and efter including firm fixed effects find a negative significant relation between the two?

Comment: Just check whether they are correlated. When u find a linear regression w two correlated variables they cannot take on the same coefficient

Comment: Which ones? I am sorry to tell you that i understand pretty much nothing about statistics :(